# Continuously read data from tcp server with specified time interval

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, windows

I need to implement tcp socket Client. We have to receive data from server tcp socket with specific time interval.If we made the connection request from client then the connection will not get disconnected .we have to receive the data whenever the server sends the data.I have tried the asynchronous client communication from MSDN website. But the Receive callback function is called within receive method.So we have to receive data from server without any interval.If the data is not received continously the connection will gone to received done and the connection disconnected.

Can anyone help me...Thanks inadvance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Transactions;

namespace ClientSocket
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        public class StateObject
        {
            public Socket workSocket = null;
            public const int BufferSize = 5176;
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        }

        public class AsynchronousClient
        {
            public const int port = 8095;

            public static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
                new ManualResetEvent(false);
            public static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
                new ManualResetEvent(false);
            public static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
                new ManualResetEvent(false);

            public static String response = String.Empty;

            public static void StartClient()
            {
                try
                {
                    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.89");
                    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

                    Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                    client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                        new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);

                    connectDone.WaitOne();
                    client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);

                    //Send(client, Msg + "<EOF>");
                    //sendDone.WaitOne();

                    Receive(client);
                    receiveDone.WaitOne();

                    MessageBox.Show(response, "Final Response received");


                    //Send(client, "Data From Client" + "<EOF>");
                    //sendDone.WaitOne();

                    //client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    //client.Close();
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
                //finally
                //{
                //    response = string.Empty;
                //}
            }

            public static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                try
                {
                    Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                    client.EndConnect(ar);

                    MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Socket connected to ",
                        client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()));

                    connectDone.Set();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
            }

            public static void Receive(Socket client)
            {
                try
                {
                    StateObject state = new StateObject();
                    state.workSocket = client;

                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
            }

            public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Receivecallback");
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                state.sb.Clear();
                Socket client = state.workSocket;

                try
                {
                    // Read data from the remote device.
                    int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                    {

                        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                        MessageBox.Show(state.sb.ToString(), "Data");


                        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                        //{
                        //    response = state.sb.ToString();
                        //}
                        //////Send(client, "NG", "Error");
                        //receiveDone.Set();
                        client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);

                        //state.sb.Clear();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Send(client, "NG", e.Message.ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
            }

            public static void Send(Socket client, String data, String ErrorMessage)
            {
                byte[] Status = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                byte[] errorMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ErrorMessage);
                byte[] statusSize = new byte[240];

                int i = new int();
                foreach (var ST in Status)
                {
                    i++;
                    if (i == 1)
                        statusSize[0] = ST;
                    if (i == 2)
                        statusSize[1] = ST;
                }
                if (data.Equals("NG"))
                {
                    int j = 2;
                    foreach (byte em in errorMessage)
                    {
                        statusSize[j] = em;
                        j++;
                    }
                }

                client.BeginSend(statusSize, 0, statusSize.Length, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
            }

            public static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                try
                {
                    Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                    int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Sent bytes to server.", bytesSent.ToString()));
                    //SocketConnected(client);
                    sendDone.Set();
                    //MessageBox.Show("Send Callback");

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
            }
            public static bool SocketConnected(Socket s)
            {
                bool part1 = s.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
                bool part2 = (s.Available == 0);
                if (part1 && part2)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }


        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AsynchronousClient.StartClient();
        }



        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you have started already to implement such a interval routine. Would you care to post it? This would be a good starting point.

Comment: I have attached my code.it receives only the first response.If the server send data after some time, then how can i get that data from this code.

Comment: can anyone help me based on the above code

Answer (score 0):

Create socket client in new thread and then start reading for forever.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace TCPClient
{
class TCPClient
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TCPClient client = null;
        client = new TCPClient("filename");

    }

    private String m_fileName=null;
    public TCPClient(String fileName)
    {
        m_fileName=fileName;
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ClientThreadStart));
        t.Start();
    }

    private void ClientThreadStart()
    {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
        clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),31001));

        // Send some data if erquired.
        clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("testdata"));

        // Receive the data whenver available.
        while(1)
        {
        byte [] data = new byte[1024];
        clientSocket.Receive(data);
        int length=BitConverter.ToInt32(data,0);

    //check if  you have received all the data and sleep for time interval. with Sleep(timeInterval), Do only after you have received all available data for instance.
        }

        clientSocket.Close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You should never sleep within the receive loop. This will eventually overflow the receive buffer or it might block the server while sending.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen thanks! You are right, it might overflow the receive buffer. but will not block server. because tcp server don't wait for client to receive all the data.I will modify answer accordingly. (Y)

Comment: Yes it can block the server, because TCP is a stream. When the receive buffer gets full, the server will get a message (tcp layer) that the clients receive buffer is full (something with a `tcp set window size`), and you server (if implemented blocking (default)) will block execution.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I was not aware of this, Learned it now. Thanks!

Comment: If you implement the server yourself, you might want to check `non-blocking` sockets. You will receive an error code when the clients receive buffer is full  (WOULD_BLOCK). This way you can define your own loop for resending. This is usefull for a server with many clients (over internet). Every time a socket would block, it will consume a thread.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is, that for receiving, the other side is determing how much and when it will send data. You should create some sort of request message, but you must do continues receives.

- So send the server a request for data on a interval.
- Continues receiving.